# Beginning Oracle, PL/SQL Programming?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have spent a few years doing more functional programming (and concurrent programming) than Object oriented. I  have so been glued to `Mnesia DBMS` which comes bundled in the **[Erlang/OTP System from Ericsson](http://erlang.org/)**.
 Also, we have used **[MySQL Cluster Storage](http://www.mysql.com/cluster/)** for handling Large Data sets behind Mnesia Nodes which handle temporary, live information. The architectures we have in place are so far stable. However, in a recent project, suggestions of kicking in Oracle were common place because of its stability and massive support. Oracles product, Times Ten In-Memory Database is being used too, in building Telecom systems. Erlang/OTP works very well with MySQL and MySQL Cluster Products because it provides ODBC libraries and numerous sql drivers.
Mnesia does create In Memory Databases that are efficient. Recently, i downloaded and installed `Oracle Times Ten In-Memory Database`. Now basing on that simple introduction, here the main body comes...
In the recent project we have worked on, we used mnesia for holding distributed session data in Main Memory. Mnesia's performance is good so far, but our users are increasing in number. In the future, we may need to have several options for in-Memory Storage. We may also need to compare the performance of our existing solution with the one that Oracle Times Ten may give to us. I would like to see and experiment with the performance of Oracle Times Ten, so that in a future project i can make informed decisions based on an experience of the two DBMS. 
I have it running and i would like to get started with `PL/SQL`, its Query Language. Where would an Oracle newbie start from, especially concerning the selection of database (11g, 10g, 9i, e.t.c.) and PL/SQL in particular? Any sites, pdfs, tutorials for a PL/SQL beginner will be very helpful. Also, provide some highlights on the several options of accessing data (writing, reading, updating and deleting) with Oracle databases from different application memory space (Database Connections, Pipes e.t.c), in general (basing on my Mnesia and MySQL background)
 thanks in advance

Comment: any introductory highlights are welcome, thanks

Comment: For free resources see [List of freely available programming books][1] sections Oracle and PL/SQL 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/203968

Comment: [this](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-plsql.html) is where I got started. It will only help you understand the basic. Other than that, it doesn't promise anything. Most of my knowledge of PL/SQL is from projects. So, after you get started, just jump into the project and have fun :)

Comment: If you know procedural languages and SQL, you can combine that knowledge. I found every specific answer I needed in Google. This question is too broad, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a fast start:
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-plsql.html

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, first goto the official docs.  See the [Oracle PL/SQL Language Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm) for a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with some book. Usually things are described better in books for the beginners.

O'Reilly books are quite cheap when comparing the material e.g. one book is offering and Steven Feuerstein is an excellent author!